# Getting Error with VNC: Session is already running

Tags: solaris-10

While starting VNC session in Solaris 10 I am getting below error:

## vncserver :0

A VNC server is already running as :0

## ps -ef | grep -i vnc

root 19790 15407   0 05:55:22 pts/3       0:00 grep -i vnc
#

however there is no sessions running at :0. I am not very sure if somewhere we have to define :0 port or not.

Comment: May I suggest that you ask this question at http://serverfault.com/?  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: can you provide the command you use to start the new vnc session? are you explicitly requesting for display :0 ?

Comment: No, I am trying command as below:

$ vncserver :0

Comment: When running `vncserver :0` you are explicitly requesting VNC to use display :0 - Can you try running just `vncserver` or `vncserver :17` to see if you still get this error for other displays?

Comment: Check port starts from 6000/tcp too. That's the X11 display port need by VNC.

Answer (score 8):

For me, as suggested in the comments, the solution was to delete some temporary files from a previous run:

```
rm -f /tmp/.X0-lock
rm -f /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
```

Comment: Its important to replace 0 with the display number. For example X1-lock..X2-lock.

Comment: In case of multiple users, the display number might belong to a different user. Then deletion is not possible. Another display number can be used.

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of efforts I found removing .vnc folder(inside $Home) resolves the issue.
.VNC folder is created every time you run the vncserver. This folder has a file that has a process Id of vnc to kill.
In case the vncserver process hangs and doesn't even shows in ps -ef command, remove the .vnc folder, after that vncserver will be able to create new .vnc folder and kill the existing process.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that display :0 is locked by a previous failed\crashed vnc session.

You can kill the :0 session by running:

```
vncserver -kill :0
```

From vncserver man page:

> ```
>  -kill :display#
>       This  kills  a  VNC  desktop  previously  started  with
>       vncserver.   It  does this by killing the Xvnc process,
>       whose   process   ID   is   stored    in    the    file
>       "$HOME/.vnc/host:display#.pid".    The   -kill   option
>       ignores anything preceding the first colon (":") in the
>       display  argument.   Thus,  you  can  invoke "vncserver
>       -kill  $DISPLAY",  for  example  at  the  end  of  your
>       xstartup file after a particular application exits.
> ```

You can also check if the lock files are still there. here is the relevant files, from the man page:

> FILES
>        Several  VNC-related  files  are  found  in  the   directory
>        $HOME/.vnc:
>
> ```
>  $HOME/.vnc/xstartup
>       A shell script specifying X applications to be run when
>       a VNC desktop is started.  If this file does not exist,
>       then vncserver will create a  default  xstartup  script
>       which attempts to launch your chosen window manager.
>
>  $HOME/.vnc/passwd
>       The VNC password file.
>
>  $HOME/.vnc/host:display#.log
>       The log file  for  Xvnc  and  applications  started  in
>       xstartup.
>
>  $HOME/.vnc/host:display#.pid
>       Identifies the Xvnc  process  ID,  used  by  the  -kill
>       option.
> ```

For example, I started vncserver with :22 and then killed it (twice):

```
[raamee 25 0 ~]$ vncserver :22

New 'myhost:22 (raamee)' desktop is myhost:22

Starting applications specified in /home/raamee/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/raamee/.vnc/myhost:22.log

[raamee 26 0 ~]$ vncserver -kill :22
Killing Xvnc process ID 22733

[raamee 27 0 ~]$ vncserver -kill :22

Can't find file /home/raamee/.vnc/myhost:22.pid
You'll have to kill the Xvnc process manually
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I have tried all the options like killing the sessions and finding the session from ps -ef. but pid is not there to kill

Comment: Try manually removing the files I listed from the help. `$HOME/.vnc/host:display#.log` and `$HOME/.vnc/host:display#.pid` and `/tmp/.X#-lock`

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
sudo netstat -anp
```

you will find that xinetd is holding the ports.

```
tcp     0   0 0.0.0.0:5901      0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN      531/xinetd      
tcp     0   0 0.0.0.0:5902      0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN      531/xinetd
```

shown above as pid 531

```
kill 531
```

and you are good to go.
I 'fixed' mine by editing /etc/xinetd.d/Xvnc to look like this

```
service Xvnc
{
        type = UNLISTED
        disable = yes
        socket_type = stream
        protocol = tcp
        wait = yes
        user = root
        server = /usr/bin/Xvnc
        server_args = -inetd :1 -query localhost -geometry 1920x1080 -depth 24 -once -fp /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc -DisconnectClients=0 -NeverShared passwordFile=/root/.vncpasswd -extension XFIXES
        port = 5905
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I ran this command >

```
lsof | grep x11
```

which gave me the port occupied by x11 process, when I killed those, my vnc port got free and I could start the new vnc session on the same.

Answer (score 0):

(many years later, for people arriving through Google Airlines)

I just suffered a similar problem. An unrelated service was listening on port 6001 (vs 5901) that according to /etc/services corresponds to x11.

Moving the service to another port fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from deleting tmp files, you might want to run
`sudo netstat -anp | grep 5901`
to see if any other process is blocking port 5901, for me, it's been used by `qemu-system-x8`, guess I'll have to start my session from '2'.